# Continuity of the probability that an inequality holds

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let function $f:[0,1]^{N+1} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable.

Let $Y_1,\cdots,Y_{N}$ be random variables with support on $[0,1]$ with continuously differentiable joint PDF.

$$g(x):= \mathbb{P}(f(x,Y_1,\cdots,Y_{N})<0).$$

There is $y^* \in (0,1)$ such that for $Y_1\gtrless y^*$,
$$
f(0,Y_1,\cdots,Y_{N})\gtrless 0.
$$
Moreover,
$$
\frac{\partial f(0,Y_1,\cdots,Y_N)}{\partial Y_1}|_{Y_1=y^*}>0.
$$

I hope to know:

1. Does the above imply $g(x)$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of $0$?
2. If not, what extra conditions may help?

Thank you.

---

I showed the result for $N=1$ in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4875563/1295158). But when I try to extend it to $N\geq 2$, I encounter a difficulty. Maybe this is not the way to go.

My thoughts for $N\geq 2$ (along a similar line to $N=1$) are the following.

$$
g(0)=\mathbb{P}(Y_1<y^* ).
$$
Since $f$ is continuous, and since $[0,1]^{N-1}$ is compact, there is $\delta>0$ such that for $x\in[0,\delta)$, for each $(Y_2,\cdots,Y_N)\in[0,1]^{N-1}$, there is $y^* (x,Y_2,\cdots,Y_{N})\in[0,1]$ such that for $Y_1\gtrless y^* (x,Y_2,\cdots,Y_{N})$,
$$f(x,Y_1,\cdots,Y_N)\gtrless 0,$$
and hence
$$
g(x)=\mathbb{P}(Y_1<y^* (x,Y_2,\cdots,Y_{N})). \tag{1}
$$
By the Implicite Function Theorem, $y^* (x,Y_2,\cdots,Y_{N})$ is continuous in its arguments for $x\in[0,\delta)$.

The difficulty I face is: can I use the fact that $Y_1,\cdots,Y_N$ follow a distribution with a continuously differentiable joint PDF to argue (1) is continuous? How can I do that?