# Continuity of $g(x)=\mathbb{P}(f(x,Y)<0)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

This is related to a question I posted before: [Continuity of the probability that an inequality holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4872424/1295158).
Since that question has not received a reply, here I post a simplified version with the $N$ random variables reduced to one random variable. This may help me or other people to think about that question.

Let function $f:[0,1]^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable.

There is $y^*\in (0,1)$ such that for $y\gtrless y^*$,
$$
f(0,y)\gtrless 0. \tag{1}
$$
Moreover,
$$\frac{\partial f(0,y)}{\partial y}|_{y=y^*}>0. \tag{2}$$

Let $Y$ be a random variable with support on $[0,1]$ with a continuous CDF. Let
$$
g(x):=\mathbb{P}(f(x,Y)<0).
$$

Is there a neighbourhood around $0$ in which $g(x)$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

When I was typing my attempt in the question, I reached the answer "yes". If you notice anything wrong, I would appreciate your pointing it out.

Claim:
There is $\delta>0$ such that $g(x)$ is continuous on $[0,δ)$.

Proof:

Since $f$ is continuously differentiable, (1) and (2) imply there is a neighbourhood around $y^*$ such that for $y\in [y^*-\delta_y,y^*+\delta_y]$,
$$
\frac{\partial f(0,y)}{\partial y}>0,\tag{3}$$
and there are $\bar{f}>0$ and $\underline{f}<0$ such that for $y\geq y^*+\delta_y$,
$$
f(0,y)>\bar{f},\tag{4}
$$
and for $y\leq y^*-\delta_y$,
$$
f(0,y)<\underline{f}.\tag{5}
$$
Since $[y^*-\delta_y,y^*+\delta_y]$, $[y^*+\delta_y,1]$ and $[0,y^*-\delta_y]$ are compact, there is $\delta>0$ such that for $x\in [0,\delta)$,

- for $y\in [y^*-\delta_y,y^*+\delta_y]$, (3) holds with $\frac{\partial f(0,y)}{\partial y}$ substituted by $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$,
- for $y>y^*+\delta_y$, (4) holds with $f(0,y)$ substituted by $f(x,y)$, and
- for $y<y^*-\delta_y$, (5) holds with $f(0,y)$ substituted by $f(x,y)$.

Hence, for $x\in [0,\delta)$, there is $y^*(x)\in [y^*-\delta_y,y^*+\delta_y]$ such that for $y\gtrless y^*(x)$,
$$
f(x,y)\gtrless 0,
$$
and hence
$$
g(x)=H(y^*(x))
$$
with $H(\cdot)$ denoting the CDF of $Y$.
By the Implicit Function Theorem, $y^*(x)$ is differentiable in $x$ on $[0,\delta)$.
Since $H(\cdot)$ is continuous, $g(x)$ is continuous on $[0,\delta)$.